# Pandas custom sorting of the rows based on a list

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe and a list, with the values of a column of a dataframe.
(the list is equaly long as the rows of the dataframe and each value appear exactly ones)
How can i sort the rows in the dataframe according to the order in the list?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
z = ["Jane", "Alice", "Bob"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `pd.Categorical` with `argsort`

```
df=df.iloc[pd.Categorical(df.user,z).argsort()]
df
    user  income
1   Jane   50000
2  Alice   42000
0    Bob   40000
```

Or `reindex`

```
df=df.set_index('user').reindex(z).reset_index()
```